# Solving random variable X probability (normal distribution) without using Excel and calculator

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am supposed to solve this task:

```
Provide the following probabilities for X ~ N(35, 9) (without using Excel or a calculator):
a) P(32 ≤ X ≤ 38)
b) P(29 ≤ X ≤ 41)
c) P(26 ≤ X ≤ 44)
d) P(35 − k ∙ 3 ≤ X ≤ 35 + k ∙ 3)
```

Since we worked all the time with Excel and calculator I was not able to solve it. I looked in the solutions and this is what is given without any other explanation:

```
sigma = 3
2*sigma =   6
3*sigma =   9

a)      P(35-sigma<=X<=35+sigma) =  68%
b)      P(35-2*sigma<=X<=35+2*sigma) =  95,4%
c)      P(35-3*sigma<=X<=35+3*sigma) =  99,7%           
d)      k =     2
            
        P(35-k*sigma<=X<=35+k*sigma) =  0,9545
```

I tried to understand which formula was used to arrive at these results but I can't figure it out. Also, what is the meaning of k in this context and why is sigma multiplied for 2 and 3?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: You left out that the mean of X is 35. Can you transform these problems into statements about Z, a normal variable with mean 0 and standard deviation 1? Can you use a normal table of values for Z?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to typically try in such problems is to transform your random variable $X$ into standard form:

$ Y = (X - \mu)/\sigma$, where $\mu$ is the mean of $X$ and $\sigma$ is the std dev of $X$.

In your problem, $\mu=35, \sigma=3$, so $Z = (X-35)/3$, or, $X = 3Z + 35$

Let's try the first one:
$P(32 \leq X \leq 38) = P(32 \leq 3Z+35 \leq 38) = P(-3 \leq 3Z \leq 3) = P(-1 \leq Z \leq 1) \approx 68\%$.

This is well known for a standard normal RV: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68–95–99.7_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)

You can solve the other problems similarly.

This seems like an illustrative exercise and uses "well-known" rules. In general, you need a calculator or at the very least a normal table for Z-values to solve these problems.